# how to prevent script tag injection/load before rendering html in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

```js
var testApp = angular.module('testApp',['ngSanitize']);
testApp.controller('TestController',function($scope,$sce){
 $scope.htmlString = "<span>Test HTML</span><script>alert('Hello Script');</script>";
 $scope.toTrusted = function(htmlContent) {
  if(htmlContent && htmlContent != "") {
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlContent);   
  }
  return "";
 };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="testApp">
<body ng-controller="TestController">
 <div ng-bind-html="toTrusted(htmlString)"></div>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.11/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/controllers/testController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using ng-bind-html for rendering string as html.Sometimes i am getting script tag in html string and i don't want to inject/load script tag.So what should i do to prevent script tag.

I have also searched the solution for this issue,somebody says that just remove script tag from string before rendering html.So please somebody suggest me.What is the better way to do that?

I am developing chat app with the help of angularjs and firebase.And for rendering chat messages i use ng-bind-html directive.What I have noticed that if user send script tag as part of chat messages but given script is being run.So I want to restrict this script to run.

Comment: Okay, I'm confused.  The script tag is in your string.  Why can't you just take it out?

Comment: You should sanitize the html string to only allow a restricted subset of tags.

Comment: I would sanitise all HTML elements and implement some form of markdown syntax for your chat messages. Makes it safer and also i find markdown much easier to write for such things (Think GitHub readme) than HTML.

Comment: I am developing chat app.What I have noticed that if user send script tag as part of chat messages but given script is being run.So I want to restrict this script to run.So please help me out i will very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using $sce.trustAsHtml, you need to use ng-bind alone.

```
<div ng-bind="toTrusted(htmlString)"></div>
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: But Aditya we can't use ng-bind directive because ng-bind directive is used to replace text content of specified html